# How to use post method of groovyx.net.http.RESTClient

Tags: json, grails

I have a RESTClient class, I want to do a POST to a web service.
My POST request will use JSON.
So in the Groovy class, the call looks like this:

```
 def restClient = new RESTClient(url)     
 def bodyContent = "{\"products\":[{\"ProductId\":1,\"ProductName\":\"Product\"}]}"

 response = restClient.post(
            headers:['Authorization': auth],
            contentType : jsonContentType,
            body: bodyContent
 )
```

the header and contenttype string is correct.
I put a JSON data as String type in the bodyContent and put into the body of the POST request.

I run this method and get error:

```
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.setPropertiesFromMap(HTTPBuilder.java:1111)
at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.<init>(HTTPBuilder.java:946)
at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient.post(RESTClient.java:140)
at groovyx.net.http.RESTClient$post.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
```

So i wonder how can i make a POST request using RESTClient?
I look into the document http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/rest.html here. The POST example is not applicable to my situation.

Comment: Are you running the client in a test case? Can you add more contents to the question? `jsonContentType`, `url` etc

Comment: I run it as an normal class, not in a test case. The jsonContentType is just a string = "application/json", the url is a localhost which provide REST service and it works well with curl command.

Comment: Which version of `http-builder` are you using?